# How to integrate HTML data tag in jinja2 form submit?

Tags: flask, jinja2

Let's say I have a button such as:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-brand" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
```

In jinja2, I could have something like:

```
{{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-brand") }}
```

And in the form, having:

```
submit = SubmitField("Yes")
```

Now, what do I do with the `data-dismiss="modal"`? How do I pass it either in the HTML or in the jinja form? I'm using flask by the way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using WtForm, so, in WtForms Fields have two way to declare custom attributes in HTML:

1) The first Way is putting in Form Definition, Like this:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField('Yes', render_kw={'data-dismiss': 'modal'})
```

2) The Second way is putting in HTML Jinja render:

```
{{ form.submit(class_="btn btn-brand", **{'data-dismiss': 'modal')) }}
```